# Are questions about problems with a Fitbit on topic?

Tags: support, on-topic

If I had a problem with my Fitbit, would it be on topic to ask about it here?

Answer (score 2):

Sadly I don't think these devices fit within SuperUser's scope.

As it is more an IoT device you might want to try [Internet of Things](https://iot.stackexchange.com/). According to their [help files](https://iot.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

> If you have a question about...
>
> - controlling, automating and sensing the environment using electronics ('smart devices'),
>
> ...
>
> ... you're in the right place!

I would say that a FitBit is a smart device that senses it's environment. You might want to check on their meta first though.

Answer (score 1):

Only if the problem was in connecting or using it with your computer.

Smartphones would not count as a computer though if your problem is with the Android application talking to it then there would be [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/) or for Apple devices you could ask at [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com).

As Burgi mentions for the actual hardware itself there may be other sites on the network that are more appropriate. There used to be a "Gadgets" site, but I believe it did not make it out of beta.